# Recursive validation in Corda transaction validity

Tags: corda

I am reading to understand and trying to adapt Corda into my project and I found this issue as one of the drawbacks of corda: [link](https://www.multichain.com/blog/2018/05/r3-corda-deep-dive-and-technical-review/).

Basically, in Corda, since no one holds all the ledger. So if one node receives a tx proposal, he must also prove that the tx input is also valid by recursively verifying all txs that create this input from the issuance tx.

Can someone explain or point me out or show me where can I read more about this from the official documentation of Corda. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about Notaries. Please check here:

https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-notaries.html

Comment: As I understand, the Notary provides non-validating and validating services. Yes, the issue from my attached link is solved if it is the validating notary. However, regarding the other service, the privacy issue as explained in the article is correct, isn't it?